# How can I add default values for ember has many relationship?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm using Ember `2.5.0` and I have two models `service` and `availability` which looks like:

```
// availability
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  day: DS.attr('string'),
  enabled: DS.attr('boolean'),
  startAt: DS.attr('string'),
  endAt: DS.attr('string'),
  service: DS.belongsTo('service')
});
```

And `service` which looks like:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  availabilities: DS.hasMany('availability',
    {
      defaultValue:
        [
          {
            day: 'saturday',
            enabled: false,
            startAt: '',
            endAt: ''
          },
          {
            day: 'sunday',
            enabled: false,
            startAt: '',
            endAt: ''
          }
        ]
    }
  )
});
```

As you can see I was trying to use `defaultValue` but with no luck. For new route I want to set default values if we are creating a new `service` record.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just specify them explicitly when calling `createRecord`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument hash that `DS.hasMany` only accepts two properties: `async` and `inverse`. It doesn't accept a `defaultValue` property though. ([source](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.5.3/addon/-private/system/relationships/has-many.js#L11)).

But fear not, Eki Eqbal! I think you can accomplish something similar by using your model's `ready()` hook.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  availabilities: DS.hasMany('availability', { async: true }), // is the data loaded async?

  ready() { // fires when the model is loaded from server or created locally
    if (!!this.get('availabilities')) {
      // don't set to defaults if availabilities is not null
      return;
    }

    var saturday = this.store.createRecord('availability', {
      day     : 'saturday',
      enabled : false,
      startAt : '',
      endAt   : ''
    });

    var sunday = this.store.createRecord('availability', {
      day     : 'sunday',
      enabled : false,
      startAt : '',
      endAt   : ''
    });

    this.get('availabilities').pushObjects([saturday, sunday]);
  }
});
```